# How to create a const object that conforms to a specific type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

**I am searching for a better solution of the following**... I need to do this:

```
const FRUIT_PROPERTIES = {
   "apple": { color: "red" },
   "banana": { color: "yellow" }
} as const

const myFavoriteFruitColor = FRUIT_PROPERTIES.apple.color
```

That is fine and dandy, but I also want the FRUIT_PROPERTIES object to conform to a type like this:

```
type FruitEnum = Record<string, { color: string }>

const FRUIT_PROPERTIES: FruitEnum = {
   "apple": { color: "red" },
   "banana": { color: "yellow" }
} as const
```

But this way I am loosing the original inferred type and autocompletion of the "apple" and "banana" keys.

So I have solved this by doing the following

```
type FruitEnum = Record<string, { color: string }>;

const validateFruitEnum = <TParam extends FruitEnum>(param: TParam) => {
   return param;
};

const FRUIT_PROPERTIES = validateFruitEnum({
   apple: { color: 'red' },
   banana: { color: 'yellow' },
} as const)
```

This way I retain the original type...

**But I was wondering if there is some better way of doing this? Does anybody have any better solution?**

Comment: `type FruitEnum = Record< 'apple'|'banana', { color: string }>;`

Comment: You can't infer literal type and at the same time make sure it conforms some interface in other ways. I think `validateFruitEnum` is the best way

Comment: you could make a fruit enum with banana and apple, idk if that improves anything or just adds complexity

Comment: @glinda93 Sorry I did not say this in the question, but this is what I am trying to avoid, explicitely defining the type is not ideal as the real object I am working with is big and complex and I would have to duplicate a lot of things while the type that it is supposed to conform to is quite generic...

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yep I could not think of any better solution and just wanted to be sure I am not missing something... Thanks for the response

Comment: I wonder what would it take to create something that does what `validateFruitEnum ` does, but just in a more general form like `validateShape<T>(obj: some_type_that_extends_T) => obj`, if that's a better option at all than any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So TS has added this exact functionality in the 4.9 version.

It is the new `satisfies` operator, see the announcement [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#the-satisfies-operator)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Solves the OP with very little change.

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to infer literal type without using `as const` assertion:

```js
const validateFruitEnum = <
  Color extends string,
  Value extends { color: Color },
  Prop extends string,
  Obj extends Record<Prop, Value>
>(param: Obj) => param

const FRUIT_PROPERTIES = validateFruitEnum({
  apple: { color: 'red' },
  banana: { color: 'yellow' },
})

FRUIT_PROPERTIES.apple.color  // red
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBANwIYBsCWATJMCmAxAJwFc0YBRCIgWzgF44AeYOOAYTBTALhwA9cIGKHFgE0EAOYAaZnABqqIjh78cg4QG844TgQBcbDlzgBfGSwAKBMAAcVAoSJhjJ5uAHkARgCt7axwBKOOAEGAxWtlLyijgAfMCxABQ2SARIVAZe3gCUdLFwKWlUwKCQsHB4AQCqAJIAKgD6FgHuFmQBdTVkAMp0iKiY2PjEpBTUiRqySDY2KDgGWjpcBgDkBDgYK6ZunkgQe0gL2kb6cCsAnjgonADuW2bAJtkllbWNza3tnT0AdNOzOB%20S24cAA9KC4OsMEA)

Using explicit type disables `as const` assertion. For instance `string[] as const` can't give you literal type as well as `const a:string[]=['a','b'] as const`

Answer (score 1):

You need a source of truth for the fruit types. So here is what I would do instead of using the validateFruitEnum function, although not exactly what you were looking for:

Define a fruits enum before and use that:

```
const FruitEnum = {
  apple: "apple",
  banana: "banana",
} as const;

type FruitToColorMap = Record<keyof typeof FruitEnum, { color: string }>

const FRUIT_PROPERTIES: FruitToColorMap = {
   "apple": { color: "red" },
   "banana": { color: "yellow" }
};
```

link: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2AMQE4FcCWcCiVUFtgBeYAbwChRQBDABxoBsBTALmACJaHG2AaCy4ACMqUEVVZtho0b34gAvsCoxw0eAG45wLXACeNRkjSYAKhADCEehGQBZWkWAAlRpGQATADwBrRrogAZsB6BoFGGNi4eDykqtbIrPDI6FAA5sDyAHxkWpCwCIhOAKoAkiYA%20gAKTgDylVhOJiVYAMqsKBFmlvH2NI7kAiAcdExsrCRxNhLIjO5sGXyD7FJiY7GQ8RK6jPTWAO7z8lry6kA)